# giving a pointer of object as an argument

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Assume I have

```
void func(foo & obj)
```

and I have

```
foo * object;
```

How do I make `object` into an argument of `func`?

Comment: If the pointer `object` actually points to something, you just use dereferentiation: `func(*object)`. But that's a very basic question, you should perhaps start with a C++ textbook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just dereference it:

```
func( *object );
```